# how to prevent android app orientation when opening camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I am making a simple android app that takes photos and saves image views as bitmaps, the problem is when I open the camera intent the screen rotates and then all the bitmaps are gone, I have tried many things and one of them is

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Also I tried using onSaveInstanceState but nothing works, here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing Variables
    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bsettings);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bnext);
    takePic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bpic);

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVthumbnail1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVthumbnail2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVthumbnail3);


    // Handling event listeners
    takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageView1.getDrawable() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image is NOT null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (imageView1.getDrawable() != null) {
        bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
        tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable("bitmap1", tempBitmap);
    }
    if (imageView2.getDrawable() != null) {
        bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView2.getDrawable();
        tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable("bitmap2", tempBitmap);
    }
    if (imageView3.getDrawable() != null) {
        bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView3.getDrawable();
        tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable("bitmap3", tempBitmap);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap1") != null) {
            tempBitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap1");
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap2") != null) {
            tempBitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap2");
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap3") != null) {
            tempBitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap3");
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if (imageView1.getDrawable() == null) {
            System.out.println("1");
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else if (imageView1.getDrawable() != null && imageView2.getDrawable() == null) {
            System.out.println("2");
            bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
            tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            System.out.println("3");

            bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView2.getDrawable();
            tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            imageView3.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
            bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
            tempBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        }
        bitmap = null;
        tempBitmap = null;
        bitmapDrawable = null;

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        //  bitmapUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        //  bitmapPath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(bitmapUri));


    }
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to prevent orientation changes.  Instead, you should be saving your progress to a database or some other storage so that when your app has a configuration change, it can resume where it left off.

Comment: I have used "onSavedInstanceState" but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I open the camera intent the screen rotates and then all the bitmaps are gone

Not only do you need to handle configuration changes — such as an orientation change — but you also need to handle the case where your process gets terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. This happens more frequently than you might expect.

> Also I tried using onSaveInstanceState but nothing works

Well, the approach that you are taking may not work. I would not assume that you can get the `Bitmap` back out of the `ImageView`. More importantly, the saved instance state needs to be under 1MB, and three photo bitmaps might exceed that.

Since you need to handle process termination as well, you will need to save these three bitmaps to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) somewhere. You can put the `File` objects into the saved instance state `Bundle`, then use your favorite [image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) to load those images back in as needed.

Comment: You are right, only shared preferences fixed my problem. Thank you.